# xml element sorting using attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below XML which needs to be sorted based on its attribute

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<metadata xmlns:ame="http://www.abcd.com/ame/md">
    <logicalModel>
        <tables>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/SS_PA_BROKER_EIOPA_CODE.md"/>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/SS_XX_SOURCE_SYSTEM.md"/>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/GL_XX_COUNTRY_CODE.md"/>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/SS_PA_SOURCE_PRODUCT.md"/>
        </tables>
    </logicalModel>
</metadata>
```

Tried using xsl but not able to do so.
expected output is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<metadata xmlns:ame="http://www.abcd.com/ame/md">
    <logicalModel>
        <tables>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/GL_XX_COUNTRY_CODE.md"/>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/SS_PA_BROKER_EIOPA_CODE.md"/>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/SS_XX_SOURCE_SYSTEM.md"/>
            <table ame:include="md/logical/tables/SS_PA_SOURCE_PRODUCT.md"/>
        </tables>
    </logicalModel>
</metadata>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: The expected output does not look "sorted based on its attribute". Please explain the logic that needs to applied here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found below xsl which can sort entire xml tree as expected

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
      <xsl:sort select="text() | @*"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This does not produce the expected output: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBG9

Comment: And it's still different from the output produced by your code.

Comment: I don't know of a solution to a problem I do not understand. I asked you to explain the logic, but you did not.

Comment: ok. may be i will explain in detail. above xsl has given sorted output in chrome development console and i can live with it. added screenshot of the dev tool in answer.